# manually search an inverted index

Tags: mysql, search, inverted-index

I created an inverted index from documents within 2 tables:

- index_token(token_id,token)
- index_documents(doc_id,token_id,storage_document_id)

Now i want to select documents where the words 'cat' and 'dog' occur in the same storage_document.

My attempt was:

> SELECT * FROM index_token INNER JOIN index_documents ON index_token.token_id = index_documents.token_id WHERE index_token.token = 'cat' **OR/AND** index_token.token = 'dog'

OR makes the 2nd token optional so i get documents that have dog or cat, but not dog and cat.
AND gives me no results.

So how do i have to change the query to get the expected results?

It also should accept more than 2 keywords.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dog_docs.doc_id from
(
SELECT index_documents.doc_id 
FROM index_documents 
INNER JOIN index_token
ON index_token.token_id = index_documents.token_id
WHERE index_token.token = 'cat'
) cat_docs
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT index_documents.doc_id 
FROM index_documents 
INNER JOIN index_token
ON index_token.token_id = index_documents.token_id
WHERE index_token.token = 'dog'
) dog_docs
ON cat_docs.doc_id = dog_docs.doc_id
```

Comment: yeah it goes into the right direction but the document reference that has to be in common is storage_document_id, doc_id is just the primary key of index_documents

Comment: but i wonder if there is a more extendable solution? so i have to add a whole new INNER JOIN block for each additional keyword... not very nice, but i think it works